# How to create a nested list from an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, nested-lists

I have an tags object from [treetagger's](https://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage) python wrapper that apparently is list:

```
In:
print type (tags)
Out:
<type 'list'>
```

When I print the content of `tags` as follows, I get the following lists:

```
In:

def postag_directory(input_directory, output_directory):
    import codecs, treetaggerwrapper, glob, os
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.txt'))):      
        with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            lines = [f.read()]
            #print 'lines:\n',lines
            tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG = 'en')
            tags = tagger.TagText(lines)

            print '\n\n**** labels:****\n\n',tags

Out:

[[u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur']]


[[u'This\tDT\tthis', u'my\tPP$\tmy']]


[[u'was\tVBD\tbe', u'to\tTO\tto', u'be\tVB\tbe', u'my\tPP$\tmy', u'camera\tNN\tcamera', u'for\tIN\tfor', u'long-distance\tJJ\tlong-distance', u'backpacking\tNN\tbackpacking', u'trips\tNNS\ttrip', u'.\tSENT\t.', u'It\tPP\tit']]
```

However, **I would like to get just one single nested list like this**:

```
[[u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur'],[u'This\tDT\tthis', u'my\tPP$\tmy'],[u'was\tVBD\tbe', u'to\tTO\tto', u'be\tVB\tbe', u'my\tPP$\tmy', u'camera\tNN\tcamera', u'for\tIN\tfor', u'long-distance\tJJ\tlong-distance', u'backpacking\tNN\tbackpacking', u'trips\tNNS\ttrip', u'.\tSENT\t.', u'It\tPP\tit']]
```

I all ready tried with `list()`, `append()`, `[]` and also with:

```
        for sublist in [item]:
            new_list = []
            new_list.append(sublist)
            print new_list
```

Any idea of how can I nest each list from `tags`?.

Comment: Putting `new_list = []` into the loop will empty the list each time.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I quit `new_list` from inside the loop. The behaviour is still the same @cricket_007

Comment: I think the real solution to this problem is to fix the source of `item` to not make lists of lists.

Comment: Have you tried `+=` instead of append? (Make sure you have `new_list = []` out of the loop when implementing this)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Adib I added more details to the question!

Comment: @Adib, I all ready tried with `+=` and get separated lists insted of a single nested list.

Comment: When you do `lines = [f.read()]` you are putting `f.read()` into a list. Are you sure that's what you need to do? Maybe you wanted `f.readlines()` or `f.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a list of one element (another list).

```
[[u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur']]
```

So if `item` is a list of lists, each with one element, then you can do

```
new_list = [sublist[0] for sublist in item]
```

If you had more than one element in each sublist, then you'll need another nested loop in that.

---

Though, in reality, you shouldn't use `lines = [f.read()]`. The documentation uses a single string when you use `tag_text`, so start with this

```
# Initialize one tagger
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')
# Loop over the files
all_tags = []
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.txt'))):      
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # Read the file
        content = f.read()
        # Tag it
        tags = tagger.tag_text(content)
        # add those tags to the master tag list
        all_tags.append(tags)

print(all_tags)
```

Comment: thanks for the help!, I added more details to the question!

Comment: @ml_student I think this solution works. I tested it, and it created the output you wanted

Comment: The desired output should be like this: `[[u'I\tPP\tI', u'am\tVBP\tbe', u'an\tDT\tan', u'amateur\tJJ\tamateur'],[u'This\tDT\tthis', u'my\tPP$\tmy'],[u'was\tVBD\tbe', u'to\tTO\tto', u'be\tVB\tbe', u'my\tPP$\tmy', u'camera\tNN\tcamera', u'for\tIN\tfor', u'long-distance\tJJ\tlong-distance', u'backpacking\tNN\tbackpacking', u'trips\tNNS\ttrip', u'.\tSENT\t.', u'It\tPP\tit']]`

Comment: And if `item` is a list of three lists, each with one item, then my answer should work.

Comment: My output looks something like this: `[u'I', u'a', u'a', u'a', u'p', u'a', u'o', u't', u'D', u'c', u'w', u'a', u's', u'o', u'l', u'.', u'H', u't', u'c', u'd', u'n', u'e', u't', u'n', u'f', u'a', u'h', u'i', u'f', u'j', u'd',`

Comment: Well, then `item` is not truly of the form `[ [[1]], [[2]], [[3]] ]`

Comment: I actually would like to get something like this: `[ [1] , [2] , [3] ]`, I tried your approach as follows: http://pastebin.com/mg5fjZci

Comment: And I will tell you one last time that `item = [ [[1]], [[2]], [[3]] ]` followed by the code in my answer **will** get you that output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109966/discussion-between-ml-student-and-cricket-007).